# How can I change the name of a coordinate system in SAFE FME?

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

Every time I use SAFE FME to write data in the coordinate system EPSG:25832 FME names it NUTM32. I them have problems reading the data in ArcGIS Desktop because it doesn´t recognise the name NUTM32.

Is it possible to change the Name of NUTM32 to "ETRS 1989 UTM Zone 32N" in Safe FME?

Comment: Does this help https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1261/using-external-coordinate-system-names-with-coordi.html?